# How to move Slack App installation store from local machine to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, slack, slack-commands

Slack app deployment triggered on a different pod and after that in the slack app, I'm getting this error **auth.test API call result is unexpectedly None** and I need to install the slack app again.

Here is the sample code

```
oauth_settings = OAuthSettings(
    client_id=os.environ.get('SLACK_CLIENT_ID'),
    client_secret=os.environ.get('SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    callback_options=callback_options,
    scopes=["channels:read",
            "chat:write",
            "chat:write.public",
            "commands",
            "groups:read",
            "im:history",
            "team:read",
            "users:read",
            "users:read.email"]
)

app = App(
    signing_secret=os.environ.get('SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET'),
    installation_store=FileOAuthStateStore(expiration_seconds=600, base_dir="./data"),
    oauth_settings=oauth_settings

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution which is available in library but documentation is missing somehow

instead of using FileOAuthStateStore you can use AmazonS3InstallationStore

```
    oauth_settings = OAuthSettings(
    client_id=os.environ.get('SLACK_CLIENT_ID'),
    client_secret=os.environ.get('SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    callback_options=callback_options,
    scopes=["channels:read",
            "chat:write",
            "chat:write.public",
            "commands",
            "groups:read",
            "im:history",
            "team:read",
            "users:read",
            "users:read.email"]
)

app = App(
    signing_secret=os.environ.get('SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET'),
    installation_store=AmazonS3InstallationStore(s3_client=boto3.client('s3'), bucket_name=os.environ.get('INSTALLATION_BUCKET'), client_id=os.environ.get('SLACK_CLIENT_ID')),
    oauth_settings=oauth_settings

)
```

Make sure bucket is not public. This will store the slack installation store information in this bucket